# How to adjust the position of text automatically by using base r plot function instead of using ggplot?

Tags: r, plot, metafor

I am using `metafor` to perform subgroup analysis. However, the position of the text in the graph producing by base r is very difficult to adjust. For example,

```
#The code is from the example of the author of metafor:
#https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/plots:forest_plot_with_subgroups
library(metafor)

### copy BCG vaccine meta-analysis data into 'dat'
dat <- dat.bcg

### calculate log risk ratios and corresponding sampling variances (and use
### the 'slab' argument to store study labels as part of the data frame)
dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat,
              slab=paste(author, year, sep=", "))

### fit random-effects model
res <- rma(yi, vi, data=dat)

### a little helper function to add Q-test, I^2, and tau^2 estimate info
mlabfun <- function(text, res) {
  list(bquote(paste(.(text),
                    " (Q = ", .(formatC(res$QE, digits=2, format="f")),
                    ", df = ", .(res$k - res$p),
                    ", p ", .(metafor:::.pval(res$QEp, digits=2, showeq=TRUE, sep=" ")), "; ",
                    I^2, " = ", .(formatC(res$I2, digits=1, format="f")), "%, ",
                    tau^2, " = ", .(formatC(res$tau2, digits=2, format="f")), ")")))}


### set up forest plot (with 2x2 table counts added; the 'rows' argument is
### used to specify in which rows the outcomes will be plotted)
forest(res, xlim=c(-16, 4.6), at=log(c(0.05, 0.25, 1, 4)), atransf=exp,
       ilab=cbind(tpos, tneg, cpos, cneg), ilab.xpos=c(-9.5,-8,-6,-4.5),
       cex=0.75, ylim=c(-1, 27), order=alloc, rows=c(3:4,9:15,20:23),
       mlab=mlabfun("RE Model for All Studies", res),
       psize=1, header=F)

text(-16,26,substitute(paste(bold('Author'))),cex=0.75)
```

The output is:
[image]

The position of `Author` is not correct. If I use `mtext` instead of text:

```
mtext(side = 3,substitute(paste(bold('Author'))),cex=0.75)
```

[image]

The `Author` will be the top center instead of the top left margin.

Is there any function to adjust the position more easily? Thank you!

Update:
If I use `mtext('test',side = 3,adj = 0)`,
the graph will be like this:

[image]

which is not the graph I want.

My target output is something like this:
[image]

Comment: perhaps using the `at=` argument per the help file?

Comment: I solved it by using `header` argument in metafor::forest... I just read the document once again, and found that a vector can be inputted to specify the left and right headers...

Comment: OK `mtext('test',side = 3,adj = 0)`  also worked for me instead of "at"

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind explain `at` argument in mtext? I do not understand what is the meaning of `specify the position of each strings`. Does it mean that if I input a vector:`c('1','1','e'), I need to use `at` to specify the location of each elements in the vector?

Comment: So it turns out I was thinking of `adj` but here's an example that uses `at` perhaps it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19918566/relative-position-of-mtext-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work

```
plot(x=1,y=1)
mtext('test',side = 3,adj = 0)
```

or using "at":

```
mtext('test',side = 3, at=par("usr")[1]+0.05*diff(par("usr")[1:2]))
```

Edit to address ggplot comment:

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x=1,y=1)) +
geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y)) +
ggtitle('title') + 
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0))
```

The last line is the key, location adjusted by `hjust` argument
you'll have to mess around with the numbers to align where you want

Comment: It is not the graph I want... I want `Author`  is just above the `Author` column... Please see the update.

Comment: I added an edit, I think you would have to add a call to mtext and by trial and error find the locations for each of your headers. It may be better to use the solution you found in the metefor package...I am unfamiliar with that package/function.

Comment: I see... So there is no function that is similar to ggplot?

Comment: I added an edit to the answer, you can grab the last two lines and adapt them to your plot code

Comment: Is it ok to use in base r...?

Comment: mtext works in base r not with ggplot